# All color in PhpStorm look like they are commented out?

Tags: php, phpstorm

It looks like all the PHP code is commented out (gray but still working)

How can I change it back?

[image]

Comment: Commented php code looks like `// code...` or `/* code */`

Comment: yes but its not commented

Comment: _yes but its not commented.._ that is what I was telling you

Comment: but how to change it back to the old version whit the color? because in the editer setting font it shows it whit colors

Comment: Take alook at settings or default settings

Comment: @HashtagForgotName Either PHP plugin is somehow disabled ... or `*.php` file extension pattern is associated with a `Text File` file type... (see Rarst's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at generic file type icons in file tree, you might have disassociated `.php` extension from PHP type, as understood by PhpStorm.

Check Settings > Editor > File Types > PHP > Registered Patterns

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if the `*.php` pattern is assigned to **Text** file type; please check file patterns in **Preferences | Editor | File types -> Text** file type - can you see `*.php` there? Removing it and re-assigning it to **PHP** file type should help